# What can be said about a measure with given marginal measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, optimization

Let $(X,\mathcal F_X,\mu_X)$, $(Y,\mathcal F_Y,\mu_Y)$ be two measure spaces. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\bigl(X\times Y, \sigma(\mathcal F_X \times \mathcal F_Y)\bigr)$ such that for each $A \in \mathcal F_X$ and each $B \in \mathcal F_Y$ we have
$$
   \mu(A \times Y) = \int_A f_\mu(x) \, d\mu_X(x), \quad (1) \\
   \mu(X \times B) = \int_B g_\mu(y) \, d\mu_Y(y). \quad (2)
$$
In other words, we know that marginal measures of measure $\mu$ are absolutely continuous w.r.t. measures $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ with known densities $f_\mu$ and $g_\mu$, respectively. Is it possible to say that measure $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. measure $\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y$, i.e. that there exists such function $u(x,y)$ that for each $C \in \sigma(\mathcal F_X \times \mathcal F_Y)$
$$
  \begin{align}
    \mu(C) & = \int\limits_C u(x,y) \, d(\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y)(x,y), \quad (3) \\
    f_\mu(x) & = \int\limits_Y u(x,y) \, d\mu_Y(y), \quad \text{a.e. w.r.t. $\mu_X$}, \quad (4)\\
    g_\mu(y) & = \int\limits_X u(x,y) \, d\mu_X(x) \, \quad \text{a.e. w.r.t. $\mu_Y$?} \quad (5)
  \end{align}
$$
I think that the answer in negative. In the Monge-Kantorovich problem one solves the problem of minimization
$$
   \int\limits_{X \times Y} h(x,y) \, d\mu(x,y) \to \min_\mu, \quad \text{$\mu$ satisfies (1), (2)},
$$
with known $\mu_X$, $\mu_Y$, $f_\mu$, $g_\mu$, $h$. And often it is shown that there exists a solution $\mu$, concentrated on some surface $y = F(x)$. If my considerations are correct, is it possible to say something about this measure $\mu$ in analogy with formulas (4)-(6)?